# scala-spark Array mapping

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a question about mapping Array in scala. I have the following Array:

```
Array[(scala.collection.immutable.Set[String], com.trends.City, com.trends.State)]
```

Basically, I want to map the Array such that each String in the Set will have com.trends.City and State attached to it. The result should look something like:

```
Array[(String, com.trends.City, com.trends.State)]
```

Which is like flatMap, but I want the com.trends to be in there.

I could also convert the Array into a RDD if needed and use flatMapValues, but I am concerned for the efficiency, could someone tell me what is the best way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flatMap on scala array like this:

```
class City
class State
val array: Array[(scala.collection.immutable.Set[String], City, State)] = Array()
array.flatMap(p => p._1.map(q => (q, p._2, p._3)))
```

Comment: I don't think this version works. It doesn't search if the string belongs to the Set, so it will always give a result, even if it shouldn't.

Comment: @CarlosVilchez can u explain what do u mean?

Comment: The `Array[(scala.collection.immutable.Set[String], com.trends.City, com.trends.State)]` has a Set[String] that determines if the String should be associated with that City and State.
In your code you are iterating through the list of strings in the Set and then creating each possible result.
I know it sounds complex, but bear with me. Nothing better than an example for this situation. Lets suppose we have this data:
`val cities = Array ("a", "b", "c")
val cityArray = Array ((Set("x", "y"), "b", "c"), (Set("z"), "b2", "c2"))`
The result would be:
`Array((x,b,c), (y,b,c), (z,b2,c2))`

Comment: @CarlosVilchez  I used your example and got the same result with my solution

Comment: my bad. I misunderstood the problem. Your solution is correct.