# How to un-nest a spark rdd that has the following type ((String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]]))

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

Its a nested map with contents like this when i print it onto screen

```
(5, Map ( "ABCD" -> Map("3200" -> 3,
                    "3350.800" -> 4, 
                    "200.300" -> 3)
 (1, Map ( "DEF" -> Map("1200" -> 32,
                        "1320.800" -> 4, 
                        "2100" -> 3)
```

I need to get something like this

```
Case Class( 5, ABCD 3200, 3)
Case Class(5, ABCD 3350.800, 4)
CaseClass(5,ABCD., 200.300, 3)
CaseClass(1, DEF 1200, 32)
CaseClass(1 DEF, 1320.800, 4)
```

etc etc. 
basically a list of case classes

And  map it to a case class object so that i can save it to cassandra.
I have tried doing flatMapValues but that un nests the map only one level. Also used flatMap . that doesnt work either or I'am making mistakes

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your example output doesn't make sense. Can you write it out as a scala type? List(5, ABCD,3200, 3) or something like that.

Comment: i want them as a list of case classes@JustinPihony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly straightforward using a for-comprehension and some pattern matching to destructure things:

```
 val in = List((5, Map ( "ABCD" -> Map("3200" -> 3,  "3350.800" -> 4, "200.300" -> 3))),
               (1, Map ("DEF" -> Map("1200" -> 32, "1320.800" -> 4, "2100" -> 3))))

case class Thing(a:Int, b:String, c:String, d:Int)

 for  { (index, m) <- in
        (k,v) <-m
        (innerK, innerV) <- v}
        yield Thing(index, k, innerK, innerV) 

//> res0: List[maps.maps2.Thing] = List(Thing(5,ABCD,3200,3), 
//                                      Thing(5,ABCD,3350.800,4),
//                                      Thing(5,ABCD,200.300,3), 
//                                      Thing(1,DEF,1200,32),
//                                      Thing(1,DEF,1320.800,4),
//                                      Thing(1,DEF,2100,3))
```

So let's pick part the for-comprehension

```
(index, m) <- in
```

This is the same as

```
t <- in
(index, m) = t
```

In the first line `t` will successively be set to each element of `in`.
`t` is therefore a tuple `(Int, Map(...))`
Patten matching lets us put that "patten" for the tuple on the right hand side and the compiler picks apart the tuple, sets `index` to the Int and `m` to the Map.

```
(k,v) <-m
```

As before this is equivalent to

```
u <-m
(k, v) = u
```

And this time `u` takes each element of Map. Which again are tuples of key and value. So `k` is set successively to each key and `v` to the value.

And `v` is your inner map so we do the same thing again with the inner map

```
(innerK, innerV) <- v}
```

Now we have everything we need to create the case class. `yield` just says make a collection of whatever is "yielded" each time through the loop.

```
yield Thing(index, k, innerK, innerV)
```

Under the hood, this just translates to a set of maps/flatmaps

The `yield` is just the value `Thing(index, k, innerK, innerV)`

We get one of those for each element of `v`

```
v.map{x=>val (innerK, innerV) = t;Thing(index, k, innerK, innerV)}
```

but there's an inner map per element of the outer map

```
m.flatMap{y=>val (k, v) = y;v.map{x=>val (innerK, innerV) = t;Thing(index, k, innerK, innerV)}}
```

(`flatMap` because we get a List of Lists if we just did a `map` and we want to flatten it to just the list of items)

Similarly, we do one of those for every element in the List

```
in.flatMap (z => val (index, m) = z; m.flatMap{y=>val (k, v) = y;v.map{x=>val (innerK, innerV) = t;Thing(index, k, innerK, innerV)}}
```

Let's do that in `_1`, `_2` style-y.

```
in.flatMap (z=> z._2.flatMap{y=>y._2.map{x=>;Thing(z._1, y._1, x._1, x._2)}}}
```

which produces exactly the same result. But isn't it clearer as a for-comprehension?

Comment: thank you @Paul .... your answer is a bit tricky for me to understand ..can you explain a bit more on whats happening... i'am fairly new to scala/pattern matching in particular

Comment: You're missing some cool tools if you don't know pattern matching, so I recommend you read up on it. i'll add an explanation

Comment: I am for sure .. will read up @paul any suggestions for blog pages that have involved patter matching examples. Your answer makes complete sense now . Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Any decent Scala book will cover this. I don't know of one to particularly recommend.

Comment: @The Archetypal Paul can you help and suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this if you prefer collection operation

```scala
    case class Record(v1: Int, v2: String, v3: Double, v4: Int)

    val data = List(
      (5, Map ( "ABC" ->
        Map(
          3200. -> 3,
          3350.800 -> 4,
          200.300 -> 3))
        ),
      (1, Map ( "DEF" ->
        Map(
          1200. -> 32,
          1320.800 -> 4,
          2100. -> 3))
        )
    )

    val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

    val result = rdd.flatMap(p => {
      p._2.toList
        .flatMap(q => q._2.toList.map(l => (q._1, l)))
        .map((p._1, _))
    }).map(p => Record(p._1, p._2._1, p._2._2._1, p._2._2._2))

    println(result.collect.toList)
    //List(
    //  Record(5,ABC,3200.0,3),
    //  Record(5,ABC,3350.8,4),
    //  Record(5,ABC,200.3,3),
    //  Record(1,DEF,1200.0,32),
    //  Record(1,DEF,1320.8,4),
    //  Record(1,DEF,2100.0,3)
    //)
```

Comment: thank you @ user52045  i figured this out from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080136/scala-spark-array-mapping  an hour ago forgot to write up an answer.... anyways thank you I was doing exactly the same thing .

Comment: That can be shortened. You don't need to convert Maps to Lists before mapping over them.

Comment: yeah i was about to point that out as well .. both your answers are right but pauls answer is more readable after his explanation . Thank you @Paul